# Java Classpath Error When compiling a java project from another java program

Tags: java

### I am getting a class-path error on Ubuntu v20.04 which says

```
error: invalid flag: Edition/lib/jfontchooser-1.0.5.jar";.
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

Actually, I am creating a java IDE and whenever a project having some dependecy is made to compile or execute the above error is raised up and the process executing the command exists.
The compilation of the project is done by creating a process as:

```
String pathToCompiler = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac";
String depenPath = "/home/arham/Documents/Eclipse Workspace/Omega IDE Linux Edition/lib/jfontchooser-1.0.5.jar";
Process compile = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(pathToCompiler+" -d bin -classpath \""+depenPath+"\";. @.sources", null, new File("Project Path"))
```

It is giving the same error either by creating the process from `Runtime` or by `ProcessBuilder`
[image: Here's a screenshot of the error in my IDE]

### The overall command that the `compile` process is executing is

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac -d bin -classpath "/home/arham/Documents/Eclipse Workspace/Omega IDE Linux Edition/lib/jfontchooser-1.0.5.jar";. @.sources
```

The above command works fine on **Windows 10 Pro v2004** but not on **Ubuntu v20.04 LTS**.

- When I run the above command directly on the terminal it gave **no error** but when with a `java.lang.Process` it gives an **error** (mentioned in the starting).
  **I have tried removing the **extra quotes** and by removing `;.` from the *classpath* in many combinations but it didn't worked.**

Comment: Have you considered using the [java compiler API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)? Also, are you aware that JDK 11 uses modules? Maybe you should be compiling according to module path and not class path?

Comment: Suppose if the user has multiple jdk installed both modular and non-modular and since, it is an IDE so it needs to know which execution environment the user wants to use thus, using the `JavaCompiler` API is not a suitable method

Comment: I know that java se above 8 uses modules but that will not matter because when I was on Windows and with jdk 14 my method worked sucsessfuly

Comment: In the Java JEP listing modules are not defined as a permanent change to JAVA SE so they can be removed in any new release of Java when needed

Comment: Try splitting your command line into a list of command and options and arguments, e.g. `"javac","-d","bin","-classpath","\"/home/arham/Documents/Eclipse Workspace/Omega IDE Linux Edition/lib/jfontchooser-1.0.5.jar\""`

Comment: I have tried this earlier using `ProcessBuilder` but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

The jar file is present with a directory structure which are having spaces. Move the jar to a different directory which doesn't have spaces in them (ex: /home/arham/Documents/jars) before you compile.

Comment: Actually, I am creating a java ide for public usage, so if i did this then i will be able to overcome the situation but how will others. This is not an appropriate answer to this question. Thank you.

Comment: Okay. One observation is that you have used semicolon to separate class path. I believe in Linux environments we need to use colon to separate the paths (:). I don't think it will fix the issue, but you may give a try.